# C: Using arrays to show guessed numbers

Tags: c, arrays, codeblocks

I am having some issues with my assignment, everything looks right to me, but obviously its not. I need to write a program where a person guesses a 5 - 9 digit number depending on selection, and when each number is guessed correctly it needs to show up in the order its guessed and keep asking until all numbers are correct. The number is seeded randomly with s(rand).

Here is the assignment instructions

```
Problem: Codebreaking!

The basic idea is this:
1) You begin by selecting a length and difficulty for the code. A set of numbers will be generated.
2) You will guess the magnitude and placement of each of the numbers.
3) Anything exactly correct will be revealed.
4) Anything with the correct value will be noted, but not revealed.
5) You can guess as many times as you want.

When the correct code is entered, the program will end.
```

Output Sample

```
Welcome to Codebreaker Training!
You will be presented with a set of hidden values. Your job is to guess these values and their correct order. After each guess you will be given feedback.
Values that are correct in magnitude and in the correct location will be revealed. These are perfect matches.
Then you will be told how many other numbers are correct in magnitude only. These are imperfect matches. No additional information will be revealed.
Choose a length for the code (5-10 numbers).
6
Choose a difficulty (1, 2, or 3).
1
There are 6 numbers ranging from 1 to 3.
- - - - - -
Enter your guess: 111111
You have 1 perfect matches and 0 imperfect matches.
- - - - 1 -
Enter your guess: 232112
You have 1 perfect matches and 2 imperfect matches.
- - - - 1 -
Enter your guess: 222113
You have 3 perfect matches and 0 imperfect matches.
- 2 - - 13
Enter your guess: 323313
You have 6 perfect matches and 0 imperfect matches.
Congratulations! You guessed all the values!
```

Here is the code I have

```
//pre-processor directives
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

//Function Prototypes - do not change these
void greeting();
void setParameters(int * length, int * difficulty);
int * createHideList(int length, int difficulty);
int * createShowList(int length);
void display(int showlist[], int length);
void getGuess(int guesss[], int length);
void processGuess(int hidelist[], int showlist[], int length, int guess[]);
int solved(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length);
int PerfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length);
int ImperfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length);
void copyArray(int dest[], int source[], int length);

//Main function - This is the final version of main. Any changes you make while
//creating the functions should be removed prior to submission.
int main() {
//Length determines the number of hidden values that must be guessed
//Difficulty determines the range of the hidden values
int length, difficulty;
//Answer, revealed, and guess are all integer arrays
//Since length is undefined at this point, no sizes have been assigned.
//This will be done in the create...List functions.
//Answer is the correct answer of the hidden values
//Revealed is the list that is shown to the user
//Guess is the user's guess
int * answer, * revealed, * guess;

//seed the random number generator
srand(time(0));

//Begin the program by showing the initial greeting to the user
greeting();

//Ask the user for the length and difficulty
setParameters(&length, &difficulty);

//Create the initial arrays of size length
answer = createHideList(length, difficulty);
revealed = createShowList(length);
guess = createShowList(length);

printf("\nThere are %d numbers ranging from 1 to %d.\n\n", length, difficulty*3);

//Loop until the user solves the puzzle
while (!solved(answer, guess, length)) {
//Show the information gathered so far and prompt the user for their next guess
display(revealed, length);
getGuess(guess, length);
processGuess(answer, revealed, length, guess);
}

printf("Congratulations! You guessed all the values!\n\n");

//These functions are necessary because we are using memory allocation functions in create...List
free(answer);
free(revealed);
free(guess);

return 0;
}

//Functions
//Pre-conditions: none
//Post-conditions: Prints a welcome message to the screen
void greeting() {
printf("Welcome to Codebreaker Training!\n\n");
printf("You will be presented with a set of hidden values. Your job is to guess these\n");
printf("values and their correct order. After each guess you will be given feedback.\n\n");
printf("Values that are correct in magnitude and in the correct location\nwill be revealed. These are ");
printf("perfect matches.\n\nThen you will be told how many other numbers are correct in magnitude only.\n");
printf("These are imperfect matches. No additional information will be revealed.\n\n");
return;
}

//Pre-conditions: length and difficulty are valid values established by the setParameters function
//Post-conditions: create an array of size length and populate it with random
// values based on the difficulty
int * createHideList(int length, int difficulty) {
//i is a counter
//array is an integer array, allocated "length" integers
int i;
int * array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);

//traverse the valid indices of the array
//assign each index a random value from 1 - difficulty*3
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
array[i] = rand() % (difficulty*3) + 1;

//return the beginning of the array to the main function
return array;
}

//Pre-conditions: length has a valid value established by the setParameters function
//Post-conditions: create an array of size length and initialize to zero
int * createShowList(int length){
//i is a counter
//array is an integer array, allocated "length" integers
int i;
int * array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);

//traverse the valid indices of the array
//assign each index an initial value of 0
for(i=0; i<length; i++)
array[i] = 0;

//return the beginning of the array to the main function
return array;
}

//Pre-conditions: length and difficulty are integer pointers
//Post-conditions: length and difficulty will be set by the user
// Function should verify that these values are valid

//What to do in this function: Prompt the user for the length of the code. Remember
//that the parameter length is a pointer, so it cannot store an integer value. You will need additional
//variables. Ensure that the user gives you a value between 5 and 10, inclusive. If their
//value is invalid, continue to prompt them until they provide a valid one. Assign length the location
//of the valid integer. Repeat this process for the difficulty parameter. Difficulty
//must be 1, 2, or 3 to continue.
void setParameters(int * length, int * difficulty) {
   int temp;
   printf("Enter the length of code: ");
   scanf("%d", &temp);
   while(temp < 5 || temp > 10)
   {
   printf("Length should be between 5 and 10 inclusive.\n");
   printf("Enter the length of code: ");
   scanf("%d", &temp);
   }
   *length = temp;

   printf("Enter the difficulty of code: ");
   scanf("%d", &temp);
   while(temp < 1 || temp > 3)
   {
   printf("Difficulty should be either 1, 2, or 3.\n");
   printf("Enter the difficulty of code: ");
   scanf("%d", &temp);
   }
   *difficulty = temp;

}

//Pre-conditions: showlist is an integer array of size length
//Post-conditions: displays the contents of showlist using - for 0

//What to do in this function: Traverse the showlist array and print a - whenever the value is 0
//If the value is not zero, print the actual value. For example, if the code is 12311 and the
//user has identified the location of the 1s, the showlist/revealed array will contain 10011
//and you should display 1--11
void display(int showlist[], int length) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   if(showlist[i] == 0)
   printf("-");
   else
   printf("%d", showlist[i]);
}

//Pre-conditions: guess is an integer array of size length
//Post-conditions: reads in the guess from a user as a string and converts it to an integer array

//What to do in this function: The user will enter their values all together. For example: 12311
//Read this in as a string and then store each individual integer value in the guess array.
//Since the elements of the input will be characters, you will need to convert to integers. For example
//you would need to convert from '1' to 1. Character representations of digits start with '0' with ASCII value 48.
void getGuess(int guess[], int length) {
   int i;
   char string[10];
   scanf("%s", &string);
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   guess[i] = string[i] - '0';

}

//Pre-conditions: both hidelist and guess are integer arrays of size length
// hidelist represents the answer the user is looking for
// guess represents the user's current guess
//Post-conditions: determines if the user has found all of the hidden values

//What to do in this function: Traverse the arrays and check to see if all of the values
//in hidelist are the same as the values in guess. If they are return 1 for true,
//return 0 for false otherwise.
int solved(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   if(hidelist[i] != guess[i])
   return 0;
   return 1;

}

//Pre-conditions: hidelist, showlist, and guess are integer arrays of size length
// hidelist represents the answer the user is looking for
// showlist shows the values the user has already discovered
// guess is the user's current guess
//Post-conditions: evaluates the current guess and updates showlist

//What to do in this function: Compare hidelist to guess. If any values match exactly,
//update the showlist to reflect the information the user has discovered. Then, print out
//the number of perfect matches the user has by calling the PerfectMatches function. Print
//out the number of imperfect matches the user has by calling the ImperfectMatches function.
//Use the statement from the samples for your printf control string.
void processGuess(int hidelist[], int showlist[], int length, int guess[]) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   {
   if(hidelist[i] == guess[i])
   showlist[i] = guess[i];
   }
   printf("You have %d perfect matches and %d imperfect matches.\n", PerfectMatches(hidelist, guess, length), ImperfectMatches(hidelist, guess, length));

}


//Pre-conditions: hidelist and guess are integer arrays of size length
// hidelist represents the answer the user is looking for
// guess is the user's current guess
//Post-conditions: evaluates the current guess and returns the number of perfect matches

//What to do in this function: Compare hidelist to guess. Return the number of times
//the value in guess exactly matches the corresponding value in hidelist.
int PerfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
   int count = 0, i;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   if(hidelist[i] == guess[i])
   count++;
   return count;
}

//Pre-conditions: hidelist and guess are integer arrays of size length
// hidelist represents the answer the user is looking for
// guess is the user's current guess
//Post-conditions: evaluates the current guess and returns the number of imperfect matches

//What to do in this function: Create temporary copies of both arrays by calling the copyArray function
//twice. This is necessary because we'll need to make changes to both arrays without modifying the
//originals. Mark out the spots on the arrays that match exactly. They will be counted in the perfect
//matches instead. Use any value that won't be present in the hidelist.

//Go through the hidelist array and look for matches in the guess array. Anytime a value matches,
//regardless of location, count it as an imperfect match and mark it so it won't get counted again.

//Return the number of imperfect matches
//Hint: you will need a nested for loop.
int ImperfectMatches(int hidelist[], int guess[], int length) {
   int count = 0, i, j;
   int hidelistDup[length], guessDup[length];
   copyArray(hidelistDup, hidelist, length);
   copyArray(guessDup, guess, length);
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   if(hidelistDup[i] == guessDup[i])
   hidelistDup[i] = guessDup[i] = -1;
   for(i = 0; i < length; i++)
   {
   for(j=0; j < length; j++)
   if(guess[i] == hidelist[j] && i != j && guess[i] != -1)
   {
   count++;
   hidelist[j] = -1;
   }
   }
   return count;
}

//Pre-conditions: dest and source are integer arrays of size length
// source represents a source array: an array to be copied
// dest represents a desitnation array: the location of the copy
//Post-conditions: dest will contain a copy of source

//What to do in this function: traverse the source array and copy each element into
//the corresponding location of the dest array
void copyArray(int dest[], int source[], int length) {
   int i;
   for(i=0; i < length; i++)
   dest[i] = source[i];

}
```

My problem is the output ends up reverses the imperfect and perfect numbers, not sure why.

```
Enter the length of code: 5
Enter the difficulty of code: 1

There are 5 numbers ranging from 1 to 3.

-----11111
You have 0 perfect matches and 2 imperfect matches.
---11
```

Please if anyone can help it would be seriously much appreciated.

Comment: You should do some debugging and report back with what you find.

Comment: im sorry what is debugging? i'm new to c programming not sure what that means.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging

Comment: from what i understand the wiki you sent, actually i don't very understand much of it, is there some kind of file i'm supposed to find in the compiler? i use codeblocks. or is it to go step by step through my code line by line and see (in which case I already did that and I'm stumped still).

Comment: A debugger loads your program and executes it step-by-step. At each step you can inspect the value of variables and by stepping you can check your program takes the path you expect. You can set breakpoints where the program halts execution so you can inspect the variables.

Comment: Could anybody help him to find the debugger in Codeblocks?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie can you refer me to a program that does that?

Comment: Google "code blocks debugger". There are many hits, including tutorials.

Comment: Your code is not of bad quality for a beginner. Describing the pre- and post conditions is very good. It will be worth while for you to invest time in learning how to debug.

Comment: So I haven't really been able to grasp the concept of debugging, so I just went through it line by line and realized I forgot the "&" sign in front of strings declaration. Now I have the issue of the imperfect and perfect numbers being reversed, I revised my post up there to show the new output. Thanks for all your help thus far

Comment: When you found the debugger software, have a look at this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ I like it for the list of good advice to keep in mind aside from learning to use a debugger.